# Extract data hash reference from perl array

Tags: perl, hash

I am new to perl.  I am returning an array of references from a function.  However I am lost as how I loop over the data.

```
sub whatever{
  my %product;
  my %resolution;
  my @data = ();
  push @data, \%product;
  push @data, \%resolution;
  return @data;
}
```

In the control sub module.

```
my @results = $whatever($dt_id);
$c->app->log->debug(Dumper(@results));
```

results

```
$VAR1 = {'IOP' => 'IOP'};
$VAR2 = {'4km' => '4km','9km' => '9km'};
```

I get the two hashes but how do I loop over them.

Comment: Can you clean up your question? The code you show, `$whatever($dt_id)` is a syntax error. Also, it is not clear (to me) what you are asking...

Comment: try this:
```perl
for my $hash_ref (@results) {
  for my $key (keys %$hash_ref) {
    say "key $key has val $hash_ref->{$key}";
  }
}
```

Comment: With a `foreach` loop. But you probably want to return a reference to the array, as that's faster. `return \@data` and then `foreach my $element (@$results) { ... }`. But also your data structures look like they make not much sense. Why are the keys and values identical?

Comment: You are using a variable called `$whatever` with args, that is not how you call a subroutine. Lose the `$` dollar sign. You should never post code that you have not tried running first, meaning run the code, then copy paste it to make sure it is *exactly* the way it was when you ran it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the two hashes seperately:

```
return (\%product, \%resolution);
```

To map over them:

```
my ($product, $resolution) = whatever(...);
for my $key (%$product) {
    # do something with $product->{$key};
}
```

Comment: Thank you i didn't think about returning them separately.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```perl
for my $hash_ref (@results) {
  for my $key (keys %$hash_ref) {
    say "key '$key' has value '$hash_ref->{$key}'";
  }
}
```